# How to update a python package?

Tags: python, package

I downloaded a python package for simulated annealing from a repository on Github and successfully installed it. I now want to change a few parameters in the package such as the number of updates and the maximum temperature. I found the specific fields in the package and changed them. However, when I run the package, the changes don't seem to have been applied.
I have already tried pip install simanneal --update

Comment: How did you install the package? Using [pip+git](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install.html#git)? If you have forked the repository, you can change the location so that pip looks under your repository with your changes.

Comment: Perhaps `sudo pip uninstall simanneal && sudo python setup.py install` is what you want?

Comment: you should re-install it the same way you did the first time.  (and uninstall whatever extra copy of `simanneal` you may have installed with your call to `pip`.)

Comment: Maximum Temperatur can be set without changing code. What is the number of updates you talk about? It might be you don't need to change the code

Answer (score 0):

1. If simulated annealing is your own package, these answers will help you.
2. If simulated annealing is not your own package and you want to contribute, you should do a pull request.
3. If simulated annealing is not your package and you don't want to contribute you should do this:

a. uninstall the package

```
pip uninstall package-name
```

b. go to the package directory (where the `setup.py` is located)

```
cd package-directory
```

c. install the package with the changes locally.

```
pip install -e.
```

Then you can import the package with the changes you made.